# generate 1024 bit hashes on android

Tags: android, hash

I am currently looking into ways of generating one way hashes to share sensitive information like passwords to a web application backend.

Based on the documentation I cannot find any hashing algorithms that are supported by android OS that are larger than 512.

Are there any 1024 bit hashing algorithms for android?

Comment: "I am currently looking into ways of generating one way hashes to share sensitive information like passwords to a web application backend." - surely there are tried and tested techniques for doing this rather than inventing your own?

Answer (score 2):

If you'll pardon my being blunt, I think you're being a bit silly. If you stand any chance of having a use for a 1024-bit hash, your NSA liaison will tell you what to do. If what you're protecting doesn't have (at least) serious national security implications, a 1024-bit hash is pointless and silly.